# Как создать свой конвертер в Retrofit?

Tags: java, android

Как создать свой конвертер в Retrofit?

У меня есть XML, с ним трудно работать. Хотел конвертировать XML в Json, а после пользоваться.

Хотя у Retrofit и есть способ работы с XML `.addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())` Но опять таки, не удобно работать с XML. Аннотации эти непонятные, как их строить жуть просто.

Как мне реализовать это?

1. Нужно создать конвертер для Retrofit чтобы добавить туда XML
2. Надо чтобы XML попал в этот конвертер, не знаю как работает все это.
3. Конвертирую XML в Json через SimpleXML
4. После вызвать GsonConverterFactory.

1 и 2 пункты я не знаю как сделать. Нужна помощь

Comment: Какую цель преследуете? Или просто конвертнуть xml в json?

Comment: Просто конвертировать xml в json, и получить Pojo объект. 
Ну или можете посоветовать онлайн сервис для создания pojo из xml с аннотациями, думаю это решит проблему, так как в гугле я не нашел ответа

Comment: Ничего сложного в SimpleXml на самом деле нет, но конечно сам XML трудно-читаемый, особенно когда в одну строку. Да и зачем делать что-то руками, если можно заставить кого-то или что-то. Есть плагин для IDEA - POJO Generator, но в студии он чего-то не захотел работать. Ещё есть генератор на JS: https://github.com/realrunner/simple-xml-pojo-gen - скачайте как Zip, распакуйте, откройте index.html в браузере, дальше всё понятно. НО если xml какой-нибудь замороченный ручками подправлять всё равно придётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет возможности, то просто используйте библиотеку конвертации, этот вопрос уже не раз поднимался, вот например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337394/convert-xml-to-json-object-in-android

Comment: Данные проходят в XML, но вы предлагает использовать Json Converter? Отлично

Comment: @EraNewGames вы спрашиваете как конвертировать xml в json по ссылке есть пример кода и объяснение. А дальше накладывайте его на свой объект

Comment: по ссылке нет ответа как сделать в ретрофит